# jQuery accordion hiding tabs in CSS

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, media-queries, accordion

I have a [jQuery UI accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header) with Markup structure

```
        <div id="accordion2">
          <h3>title</h3>
                <div>stuff texty</div>
          <h3>title2</h3>
                <div>stuff texty</div>
        </div>
```

However, the second tab of the accordion is in a plainer format than the first (i.e. it has less pictures and is hence more mobile friendly).

I am want to use a media query to hide the first tab and its contents when screen width is less than 640px. I tried giving the first h3 and the first div tags a class of first and then used

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
        .first {
           display: none;
        }
}
```

To make them disappear... but it didn't work. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this as a CSS3 option:

```
#accordion2 h3:first-of-type
{
  display:none;
}
```

if you cannot support CSS3 then give that first heading a class name and target that.

Comment: Only deletes the header of the accordion; not the body. But I then followed the same logic, using h3:first-of-type and then div:first-of-type which worked.