# Jquery: minimize accordion tabs onclick of a tab content

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am looking for a possibility to minimize other accordion tabs if I receive a onclick in one of the accordion content if its minimized I want to keep only a bar down the screen, if user clicks on this the accordion is being shown again.
Found this ([jQuery accordion hiding tabs in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016633/jquery-accordion-hiding-tabs-in-css)) but no what I want.

Anybody has some experience on how to do this on easy way?

I prefer to wrap it up in the accordion creation, like shere:

```
$accordion.accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            heightStyle: "fill",
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                json = [];
                it = {};
                it["id"] = ui.newHeader.attr('id');
                it["filter"] = 0;
                it["search"] = $("#txt_search").val();
                json.push(it);
                var header = ui.newHeader.attr('id').split('_');
                var body = ui.newHeader.attr('id').substr(2);
                body = body.substr(0, body.lastIndexOf('_'));
                //iTransactionHandler(14, body, header[header.length - 1], json);
            },
            beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                alert($(this).find('.ui-state-active').next().attr('id'));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Any example of your code you can show us ?

Comment: I have standard code for Jquery accordion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the "not" function twinned with the "each" function might just be what you're looking for

```
$(".tab").click(function() {
    $(".tab").not($(this)).each(function() {
        $(this).close();
    });
});


function close() {
    console.log('close')
}
```

What this does is says "Close all tabs except the one that was just clicked."

If that doesn't answer your question; you're going to have to provide more information because it looks like you're just asking us to write you an accordion.

Comment: Have you tested your code ? Will never work like that ... [example](https://jsfiddle.net/7fn8pnqL/)

Comment: Dont want to close all tabs, I want to hide them and show only one which is open and the ulitmate last accordion tab. When click on the last accordion tab, I want to unhide all other tabs again. Not sure if I explain correct?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary @empiric? Care to enlighten me? :)

Comment: Ah okay I see it, my bad :c